# htaccess and 301 Redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have want to redirect

```
http://old.clients.domain.com
```

to

```
http://clients.domain.com
```

In the htaccess file, I write a permanent redirect

```
Redirect 301 / http://clients.domain.com
```

When I type old.clients.domain.com, it changes the address to clients.domain.com in the address bar, but it does not give me the page, instead it gives me this in Firefox:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

What do I do wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What's this? No wonder anyone who uses the example here is getting an Internal Server Error! *=old.clients.domain.com* is invalid.

Instead of

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} =old.clients.domain.com
```

Use

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?old.clients.domain\.com
```

So an example of the correct code would be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?old.clients.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://new.clients.domain.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

And this will work when redirecting the root domain to an addon domain and prevent errors like "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete"

Answer (score 0):

I think it also returns 301 for http://clients.domain.com/

You must put .htaccess file only for directory for http://old.clients.domain.com/

Answer (score 0):

If they point to the same root directory then the easiest way to do this is with a conditional rewrite statement in the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

Rewritecond   %{HTTP_HOST} =old.clients.domain.com
RewriteRule   ^.*$         http://clients.domain.com/$0   [R=301,L]
```

You need the guard to prevent re-redirection of valid `clients.domain.com` requests which most browsers, such as Ff, will pick up as an infinite redirect.

Comment: It gives me this error `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: Add the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` prolog and `</IfModule>` trailer.  If the ISE goes away, then mod_rewrite isn't being loaded or you've got a typo.